# Webgl can't run examples (black screen)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, 3d, webgl

I put a wamp server on my pc and then downloaded everything from a webgl sample (there were some problems but I managed to solve them).

The webGL sample won't play on my local URL
(http://localhost/mypage.htm)

everything seems fine, the chrome inspector says everything's correct and using the GL debugger extension I even managed to get a few screenshots of the sample correctly rendered.

The problem is: the rendering area remains black. It happens either on my local WAMP server and on my remote web server, the entire page loads correctly and the simulation seems running ( I can see the FPS meter running on the top left corner of the screen ), but I can't see the animation

Here's a screenshot to explain it better
[image]

Update:
Here's a screenshot with the webGL debugger, as you can see the rendering is properly done with the shaders and everything else (texture found and loaded), but the screen remains black. I'm also attaching the html file I'm using (the other are just libraries downloaded as-they-are from the webpage)
[image]

http://nopaste.info/76792079d5.html

Comment: Which sample are you using? Maybe the sample tries to download some model/texture files from a server and you broke the urls in you local copy so it can't find (and display) them?

Comment: I tried to download this
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_particles2.html
but I paid attention to the 'disc.png' texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: you will never believe this...

The line

```
<div style="cursor: pointer; width: 80px; opacity: 0.9; z-index: 10001; position: absolute; top: 0px; ">
```

caused for some weird reason the webgl demo being rendered a page down than the visible area (i.e. I just had to scroll down to find the rendering running)

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line:

```
gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
```

If you get squares where the circles were, that means that the problem is loading the texture.

WebGL (or maybe the browser) is pretty picky only letting you get a texture when running from a proper web server (I'm not sure what you're running locally).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I tried on a remote website too but the effect is the same